# sorting multidimensional-array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have an array and fill it like this

```
arr = [[],[]]
arr[0].append(post.attrib['href']) #strings
arr[1].append(int(klass)) # int
```

and i need to sort whole array by arr[1] for example input:

```
[['string3', 'string45', 'string25'], [46, 2, 12]]
```

and output:

```
[['string45', 'string25', 'string3'], [2, 12, 46]]
```

i tried

```
arr[0].sort(key = x[1].__getitem__) 
arr[0].sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
arr = sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(1))
```

but everything of this isn't working correct

Comment: What's the output of your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are sorting composite elements, create a pair of those elements you intend to sort using (`zip` or `itertools.izip`), and use [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), to select the correct key. Finally transpose back to the original format using `zip`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
zip(*sorted(zip(*arr), key = itemgetter(1)))
[('string45', 'string25', 'string3'), (2, 12, 46)]
```

This idea can be extended to multiple keys in a list.

**Steps of Execution**

```
>>> arr #Original Array
[['string3', 'string45', 'string25'], [46, 2, 12]]
>>> zip(*arr) #Unpacking the array, transposes it
[('string3', 46), ('string45', 2), ('string25', 12)]
>>> sorted(zip(*arr), key = itemgetter(1)) #Sort the Transpose Array based on second element
[('string45', 2), ('string25', 12), ('string3', 46)]
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(*arr), key = itemgetter(1))) #Transpose the result to generate the original format
[('string45', 'string25', 'string3'), (2, 12, 46)]
```

Comment: what exactly does the ' * ' in front of sorted do? I've never seen it used in front of a built in function before

Comment: `*` is used for [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: I know that, but i just don't get how it works when applied to 'sorted'

Comment: @Totem: It applies to `zip` rather than to `sorted`. The Output of `sorted` is unpacked and passed to `zip`. Let me add the steps of execution to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing your data as one list of 2-element pairs (e.g. `[(46, 'string3'), (2, 'string45'), (12, 'string25')]`) instead? Because if you did that, your problem would solve itself in one line of code:

```
l = [(46, 'string3'), (2, 'string45'), (12, 'string25')]
print sorted(l) 
# [(2, 'string45'), (12, 'string25'), (46, 'string3')]
```

By the way, they're lists, not arrays. Arrays in Python mean something else (namely, NumPy arrays).

Comment: yeah i know) but habitually after js i call it arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I find packing and unpacking arguments a little bit unintuitive at times, so

```
l = [['string3', 'string45', 'string25'], [46, 2, 12]]
[[y[1] for y in sorted(zip(l[1], x))] for x in l]
[['string45', 'string25', 'string3'], [2, 12, 46]]
```